# Удалить результат выполнения Task если ответ уже получен всеми кому нужно

Tags: .net, asp.net, асинхронность, task

Задание: если задача выполняется уже другим запросом, дождаться ответа и вернуть его. Если же в данный момент никто ничего не читает, выполнить самому и получить свой результат.

Т.е. по факту, мы не можем просто оставить результат уже когда-то полученный на будущее, а необходимо в конце как-то отследить, что все получат ответ, а уже после удалить результат задачи.

Пытался сделать так:

У меня есть Singleton-сервис и async метод внутри, в который поступают запросы из контроллера.
Метод выполняет некоторые действия в процессе чего ссылается на:

```
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> ArrayTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>();
```

с помощью

```
var task = ArrayTasks.GetOrAdd(taskName, taskName => Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                return await GetPointName();
            });
```

После чего я пишу

```
return await task;
```

и в finally

```
ArrayTasks.Remove(taskName, out var value);
```

В Task.Run добавлял дополнительно await Task.Delay(10000) чтоб можно было несколько запросов создать и проверить. В результате тестов, либо 1 проскакивает и возвращает лишь себе результат, либо 2 максимум. Остальные по новой считают таску хоть и дождались выполнения.

Что можно сделать в данной ситуации? Может, я вообще неверный подход выбрал?

Думал в сторону ивентов, но без понятия как опять отследить момент в который можно удалять задачу.

Comment: `GetPointName` возвращает задачу. Вы обернули её ещё в одну задачу в `Task.Run`. Зачем? В итоге `await task` ожидает завершение `Task.Run`, а не завершение `GetPointName`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я сократил немного.

По факту, мой Task.Run внутри себя имеет ещё await Task.Delay() и после чего обращение к ещё одному методу.

Comment: А кто эти все, которые должны получить результат? Как-то сумбурно всё описано. Надо бы переформулировать задачу, сейчас не очень понятно. Может быть вы просто кэширование пытаетесь переизобрести? Оно может быть с "протуханием" результата со временем, а не только с постоянным хранением результата.

Comment: @CrazyElf "эти все" -> клиенты отправившие запрос в контроллер.

В общем что я пытаюсь сделать:

У меня есть запрос на внешний сервис. Занимает он аля 10 секунд времени (для этого ставлю Task.Delay() для эмуляции). За это время приходят запросы на получение результата.
Проблема в том что, данные на внешнем сервисе могут поменяться даже через эти 10 секунд. Т.е. хранить их дольше чем время самого запроса нецелесобразно.
Но если уж клиенты послали запрос пока какой-то клиент уже ожидает получение ответа, я хочу им одновременно всем отдать одно и тоже.

Comment: Так, ну я вроде понял и мне кажется даже вы вполне правильную методику выбрали. Но зря вы так код кусочками показали, покажите больше цельного кода, может что-то понятнее будет. И попробуйте логировать каждый чих, может быть понятнее будет, почему всё идёт не по плану, что собственно происходит.

Comment: "Остальные по новой считают таску хоть и дождались выполнения." - как это возможно? И как вы это поняли? Значит всё-таки логируете что-то? Без логирования когда куда зашёл-вышел тут нельзя будет понять что же происходит.

Comment: Пожалуй, вам действительно нужно [кэширование](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @CrazyElf как я это понял. Открыл браузер, зашел в F12, в Network, открыл несколько вкладок таких и во время когда 10 секунд не прошли ещё (у меня же внутренний await Task.Delay() в работе ) натыкал несколько запросов в браузере.
В итоге, некоторые ответы приходили одновременно, а некоторые отдельно. И где-то было 10 секунд ожидания, а где-то 27.

Comment: @QviNSteN Вы таки логируйте. Без логов сложно так понять. Может те запросы в какую-то очередь попали и ждали когда коннект к сайту будет доступен и до них дошёл ход только когда первые запросы ответ получили и таску очистили и только после этого те другие запросы выполняться начали сервисом. Я чисто предполагаю, может вообще всё не так и в другом дело. Суть в том, что без логов когда кто куда зашёл понять нормально невозможно в многозвенной многопоточной среде. Хотя у вас есть логи веб-сервиса наверное по ним что-то можно понять, но не всё.